# React-Native-Gifted-Chat perfornance issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, socket.io, react-native-gifted-chat

[image]

When ı get this error the same message data is appending to the chat list and it gives crash then.

I am trying to write chat application with react-native-gifted-chat and I expect more than 15.000 messages from user but my gifted-chat can not even handle like 1000 message. İt gives this error.

I get data from mongodb via socket.

Is there any way to render message data with really good performance ? 
I researched a lot about it, PureComponent etc etc. nothing works :/

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to reach your goal you should replace the component that renders the messages with [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html) from react native. And set initialNumToRender to a small number like 10-15. I used this way in a similar chat app, but not with gifted-chat (one made from scratch).

Here is my method to render the messages and had no problem on any number of messages:

```js
<FlatList
    inverted
    windowSize={5}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    initialNumToRender={15}
    data={this.props.messages}
    ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
    onLayout={this.onLayout}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.message_id}`}
/>
```

Comment: I did what've you said as listview prop in gifted-chat but the same :/

Comment: This dramatically improved the performance for me wow! thank you