# Flatlist is very slow in using big data in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have a big data list of products thats paginate, in every page it load 10 item, but when i add new items to itemlist,flatlist gets very slow,As the number of pages increases, so does the loading time of new products,The function of the choose button is also slowed down.
How to speed up loading I tried all the best methods but it still did not work. Did not React Native really solve this problem?

```
 export default function Products(props) {
 const toast = useToast();
 const [isLoading, setSetIsLoading] = useState(true);
 const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [fetchStatus, setFetchStatus] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [sending, setSending] = useState(false);

  async function getProducts() {
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
  let data = {
  token: token,
  page: page,
  };
  await get_products(data)
  .then(res => {
    setItems([...items, ...res.data.data.docs]);
    setPage(res.data.data.nextPage);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }

 async function getNextPage() {
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
let data = {
  token: token,
  page: page,
};
await get_products(data)
  .then(res => {
    setItems([...items, ...res.data.data.docs]);
    setPage(res.data.data.nextPage);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }

 async function selectProduct(id) {
 setSending(true);
 console.log({id});
 let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');
 let data = {
  product_id: id
 };
 await select_products(data,token).then(res => {
 toast.show({
   description:res.data.message
 })
 setSending(false);
}).catch(rej => {
  console.log({rej})
  toast.show({
    description:rej?.response?.data.message,
  })
  setSending(false);
  })
  }
  useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
  getProducts();
  return () => {
    setItems([]);
    setPage();
    };
   }, []),
 );
 renderItem =({item}) => (
 <Card
  selectProduct={id => selectProduct(id)}
  sending={sending}
  obj={item}
  />
  )
  return (
    <View mb={20}>
    <FlatList
    data={items}
    extraData={items}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => `${item._id}-item`}
    onEndReached={getNextPage}
    maxToRenderPerBatch="13"
    ListFooterComponent={() => {
      return <ActivityIndicator color="orange" size="large" />;
    }}></FlatList>
    </View>
    );
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827438/react-native-gifted-chat-perfornance-issue/61827869#61827869

Comment: The main cause performance issue is the unnecessary rerender of list items mainly `<Card>` component. Try to avoid those rerenders either  by memoization or control when a component should rerender or not.

Comment: How do I know if unnecessary rendering is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use **map method **?
It can help you for more easily loading data

Comment: no i do not, data handle by flatlist in renderItem,